# php custom headers/column heads in csv export

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I cannot get custom column heads to show in my csv file. When I use the code below, the column headers appear above every row of data:

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$q1b.csv");

$output = fopen("php://output", "w");               
fputcsv($output, array("Date","First","Last","ID"));

foreach($data as $rowList) {
    fputcsv($output, $rowList);
}

fclose($output);
```

The csv file looks like below, with the data above the column heads:

> "10/11/2018" "Test" "Person" "id info"
>   "Date" "First" "Last" "ID"

**EDIT:::**

The following code is $data:

```
$data =  "\"".$date_formatted."\",\"".$FIRST_NAME."\",\"".$LAST_NAME."\",\"".$Identify_Prospect_UPD."\"\n";
echo $data;
```

It looks like I have the csv tied to the $data echo, which I don't think I want.  Weird!

Comment: Not sure I know enough to help, but what is `$data`? I think it would need to be a multidimensional array in this case.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the first code block because it appeared to be duplicate, except for one difference which was a syntax error. I defined some `$data` locally and ran this code and I couldn't replicate the issue. Can you confirm that the code above matches the code you are running?

Comment: My fault for the delay!  That is the code I am running and for some reason the column headers appear below each row of data. I'll keep looking. There has to be a mistake in my php

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was "operator error" ... translation...me!

I didn't realize I had my header code inside a foreach loop!

Rats!!!